# How does switch interfacing work?

Tags: voltage, current, resistance

This is a basic question, but I don't have a background in electronics so I find it difficult to wrap my head around the concept of how current flows. I have chosen this simple example of interfacing a switch with a microcontroller:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp5Xzd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It is a positive logic input switch.

Here are my questions, which I guess address the same core concept that I'm failing to understand:

1. What is the purpose of the 10 k-ohm resistor?
2. When SW1 is open, there is 'floating' current. Why doesn't that current go into micro-controller input?
3. When SW1 is closed, why does the current flow into micro-controller input and not go to ground?

Comment: What you mean by  'floating' current?

Comment: When the switch is open, the input port would be floating without the 10K resistor. But because the 10K is there, the node is pulled down to 0V. The reason for that is because the voltage across a resistor is V=IR. When the switch is open, I is very low, therefore the V is very low. The voltage difference between ground and the node gets close to 0V.

Comment: @NickWilliams Your comment looks close to what I'm after. So the sole purpose of resistor is to deal with floating current? When you say "The voltage difference between ground and the node gets close to 0V", why wouldn't the voltage difference between ground and node be 0v without the resistor? My questions are probably riddled with misconceptions. Also could you post your reply as an answer as it would be easier to comment on it.

Comment: @nidhin excuse my incorrect terminology. It's floating current or voltage, not sure. But it is because the air that the open switch is is connected to has some small charge / voltage.

Comment: How can the air have a "small charge/voltage"?

Comment: These things just happen. No one knows why...

Comment: @bytefire I didn't leave an answer because right now my knowledge of MCU GPIO is black box. I just know that when the GPIO is an input, as far as digital (1/0) logic is concerned, you usually just assume very little current is traveling into the MCU. You need the resistor there because otherwise, if you close the switch, you'll have a short from power to ground. You can never connect power to ground. If the switch is open however, you will def get 0V if the input is tied directly to ground.

Comment: Makes sense. Although I still don't fully understand some of the whys, I am at a stage where I know what happens in different scenarios. That's kinda okay for my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm bad at explaining, therefore I'll keep it brief.

1.) The 10 k-ohm resistor is there to act as a [pulldown resistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-up_resistor)(Search pull-down resistor).

2.) The term you're looking for is not floating *current*, rather, floating *logic*. It's not floating either, due to the pulldown resistor, causing the logic to be 0.

3.) Since in the chat, you told me that it's CMOS, it's not that the current flows into the micro-controller, rather, due to it having 0 resistance to 3.3V, the input is also at 3.3V.

I'd just like to add that in the case that you're really designing such circuit, I suggest that you add an [RC circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit) to debounce it.